# Rails STI: How to change mapping between class name & value of the 'type' column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, single-table-inheritance, sti

Because of company rules I can't use our domain class names; I am going to use an analogy instead. I have a table called projects which has a column called 'type' with possible values as 'indoor' & 'outdoor'. Records having indoor and outdoor have clear functionality separation and would fit pretty neatly as a STI implementation. Unfortunately I can't change the type-names and can't add classes inside the global namespace. Is there a way to specify a different value for 'type'?

Note: I am not trying to use a different column name instead of 'type' for STI. I am looking to have a different value for type, other than my class name.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: No I din't try anything. I couldn't get any good google result which would give me a hint of the direction which I can take. The solution provided by @VAIRIX works perfectly though!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
class Proyect < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Then the Indoor class but with Other name

```
class Other < Proyect
  class << self
    def find_sti_class(type_name)
      type_name = self.name
      super
    end

    def sti_name
      "Indoor"
    end
  end
end
```

The same apply for Outdoor class.
You can check sti_name in http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_sti_class/class

Comment: shouldn't the `find_sti_class` override go to the base class?

Comment: That's where I normally put it.

Comment: Take note that is you use this approach, objects found through the base class will be instantiated as base class, not as subclass. For example, Proyect.new(type: 'Other') will return an object of type Proyect with its attribute :type set to 'Other'. Whereas default behavior would be to return an object already cast as type Other.

Comment: @LikeMaBell you are right, you basically cannot create records with type `'Indoor'` by instantiating the base class. I have overridden the two methods `find_sti_class` and `sti_name` in the base class and the child classes but I cannot create a record with: `Proyect.new(type: 'Indoor')` because I get: `ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound:
       Invalid single-table inheritance type: Indoor is not a subclass of Proyect` while at the same time `Proyect.new(type: 'Other').save!` returns `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Type Other is not a valid type`

Answer (score 4):

In looking at the source code there seems to be a `store_full_sti_class` option (I don't know when it was introduced):

`config.active_record.store_full_sti_class = false`

That gets rid of the namespacing modules for me in Rails 4.2.7

Comment: Works as well in Rails 6.0.3.2. Thanks @Brian Underwood!

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 5, the Attributes API allows us to change the serialisation of any column, including the `type` column of STI models, thus:

```
# lib/my_sti_type.rb
class MyStiType < ActiveRecord::Type::String
  def cast_value(value)
    case value
    when 'indoor'; 'App::CarpetProject'
    when 'outdoor'; 'App::LawnProject'
    else super
    end
  end

  def serialize(value)
    case value
    when 'App::CarpetProject'; 'indoor'
    when 'App::LawnProject'; 'outdoor'
    else super
    end
  end

  def changed_in_place?(original_value_for_database, value)
    original_value_for_database != serialize(value)
  end
end

# config/initializers/types.rb
require 'my_sti_type'
ActiveRecord::Type.register(:my_sti_type, MyStiType)

# app/models/project.rb
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :type, :my_sti_type
end
```

Substitute your own class names and string matching/manipulation as required. See [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3ea4476942d2ba5ddc0d3b2d1f3730455661b06a) for an example.

The same mechanism also works for the `attributename_type` column of a polymorphic belongs_to association.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but a little convoluted. Essentially when you save a record of an inherited class, the method moves up to the parent class with an added 'type' value.

The standard definition:

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  def type=(sType)
  end
  ..
end

class Truck < Vehicle
  # calling save here will trigger a save on a vehicle object with type=Truck
end
```

Changing this is precarious at best in my opinion. You'll likely run into other issues.

I recently discovered AR method [becomes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes) which should allow you to morph children objects into parent objects or as the documentation suggests parents into children, you might have some luck with that.

```
vehicle = Vehicle.new
vehicle = vehicle.becomes(Truck) # convert to instance from Truck to Vehicle
vehicle.type = "Truck"
vehicle.save!
```

Not used this myself, but simply, you should be able to change the `type` column value before saving rather easily. This will likely cause a few problems with the inbuilt Active Record query interface and associations.

Also, you can do something like:

```
class Truck
 ..
 def self.model_name
  "MyNewClassName"
 end
 ..
end
```

But with this approach beware that the rest of rails, including routes and controllers will refer to the model as "MyNewClassName" and not "Truck".

PS: If you can't add classes inside your Global Namespace then why not add them inside another namespace? The parent and child can belong to different namespaces or can both belong to a unique namespace (not the global).

Comment: I have my code inside a namespace. By default the type that gets set in the db becomes 'namespace::Classname'. What I meant when I said I can't add my class to a global namespace was that just because I 'have' to retain the type value as 'Indoor' I don't want to move my class to the top namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If all that is required is stripping module names from the `type` field, the following helper module, based on VAIRIX's answer, can be used:

```
# lib/util/namespaceless_sti.rb

module NamespacelessSti
  def find_sti_class(type_name)
    type_name = self.name
    super
  end

  def sti_name
    self.name.sub(/^.*:/,"")
  end
end
```

This module has to be extended into every STI base class, e.g. `Project` from OP's description (imagining models live in `Acme` namespace/module)

```
# app/models/acme/project.rb

require "util/namespaceless_sti"

module Acme
  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend NamespacelessSti
  end
end

# app/models/acme/indoor.rb

module Acme
  class Indoor < Project
    # nothing special needs to be done here
  end
end
```

This makes sure `Acme::Indoor` records in `projects` table will have "Indoor" in their `type` field.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5.1.4 the solution of @VAIRIX not worked for me, because I had inheritance_column of integer type and Rails find_sti_class have extra cast at first line:

```
type_name = base_class.type_for_attribute(inheritance_column).cast(type_name)
```

I faced with cast issue. Even if I prepared type_name to proper class name. The cast required integer and changing any string to 0.
That is why I extended #compute_type instead and set store_full_sti_class to false:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'PolyTable'
  self.inheritance_column = 'RecordType'
  self.store_full_sti_class = false

  class << self
    def compute_type(type_name)
      type_name = case type_name.to_s
        when "4"
          "ChildOfType4"
        ...
        else
          type_name
      end
      super
    end
  end
end
```