# Rails STI namespaced classes without using type column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement STI as follows

```
module ModuleName
  class ParentName
    self.inheritance_column = 'column_name'
  end
end

module ModuleName
  class ChildName < ModuleName::ParentName
    class << self
      def find_sti_class(type_name)
        type_name = self.name
        super
      end

      def sti_name
        self.name.sub(/^.*:/,"")
      end
    end
end
```

When I try

```
ModuleName::ChildName.create(column_name: 'ChildName')
```

I am getting following error

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound: Invalid single-table inheritance type: ChildName is not a subclass of ModuleName::ChildName
```

I was trying to refer to solution provided here
[Rails STI: How to change mapping between class name & value of the 'type' column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293177/rails-sti-how-to-change-mapping-between-class-name-value-of-the-type-column)

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the `<< ModuleName::ParentName` just  a typo or do you actually have << there?

Comment: typo. will correct it. I am using < in actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I was doing was specifying the inheritance column while creating ChildName.

wrong:-

```
ModuleName::ChildName.create(column_name: 'ChildName')
```

right:-

```
ModuleName::ChildName.create()
```

It will automatically set column_name to 'ChildName'
Specifying it will make rails think that ChildName is a parent class and will look for subclasses with name ChildName

Answer (score 0):

```
module ModuleName
  class ParentName
    self.inheritance_column = 'column_name'
  end
end

module ModuleName
  class ChildName << ParentName
    # ...
  end
end
```

When you declare a class inside a module it will automatically resolve the superclass to the same module.

Thus using `ChildName << ModuleName::ParentName` will try to resolve `ModuleName::ModuleName::ParentName`. If you want to explicitly state the superclass you would use `::ModuleName::ParentName`.

Comment: Tried using both ChildName << ParentName as well as ChildName << ::ModuleName::ParentName . I am still getting the exact same error.